# text-to-speech in single purpose app/kiosk app/lock task mode

Tags: android, locking, task, text-to-speech

In my current Android project I have to use tts (to read messages) in **lock task mode** (single purpose app/kiosk app). Everything works well in 'normal' app mode but when i try use text-to-speech in lock task mode then no sound comes out.

I add `com.google.android.tts` packake to `setLockTaskPackages()` but it's still not work.

Do you have any other solutions or samples usage tts in lock task mode?

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@skajar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4287440)'s question post.

> The solution is very easy, just don't forget to set property parameters in set User Restriction()
> In my case:
>
> ```
> setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_MOUNT_PHYSICAL_MEDIA, false);
> setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_ADJUST_VOLUME, false);
> ```